Is metaphysical thumb on the scale possible in the US election?
The logic is simple (I hope).
If there is metaphysical influence in our reality, it should be detectable in this critical election.
The question is, how to look for it, in a scientifically prudent way?

If the non-existent exists, gods only know what it can do, how to detect it, or anything else really. This is not a philosophy question, this is an invitation to write fiction..

If you cannot get your mind around something (at the moment) it does not mean there is no science in there. They've been saying that Cybernetics is not science, for some period of time.

The word 'metaphysical' is going to raise eyebrows at least on this (ostensibly) philosophy forum. Also 'scientifically prudent' will invite ridicule.  Although simply, factually astrology, numerology, alchemy etc have been very much science in a different era. But today the word is jealously guarded by a certain cabal...

Im not going to get into this argument @KristianBerry, at least not on this question where it is tangential. Instead I will restate Matrix's question in more standard philosophical terms: Can the current critical election show us a way out of Plato's cave of disinformation-shadows?

10 meter tall angels with flaming swords guarding the entrances to all the polling places would be plenty to convince me, personally.

@gs You remind me of Craig vs Parsons

@rushi I would be adequately convinced by having a hallucination of 10 meter tall angels with flaming swords guarding the entrances to all the polling places, for that matter.

Vow -6 and counting ! You're winning at the downvote game. The all time record is still 2-3:away. If you reach I'll push you over. And cheerlead


The old order changeth yielding place to new and God fulfills Himself in many ways lest one good custom should corrupt the world
Tennyson

I'd ask you to study the Yoga sutra concept of abhinivesha for your peace of mind.
My rough rendering:

The inertial will to live that causes the suffering of living and paradoxically shortens life itself.

If you find the issuance of cultural, linguistic passports and visas irksome, you can get about the same from Schopenhauer who is far too under-represented out here.

While people out here seem to find nothing better to do than to mock your question, there are notable
thinkers who like you are reaching out of the Plato-cave.
